# MvcSiteMapProvider on View side with razor get parents of current node

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVC Site Map Provider for creating some breadcrumbs

what i wanna do; creating breadcrumbs on view using razor

i would like to do some calls like shown below

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div>YOU ARE HERE:
        // There is no calls like this but you get the idea
        @if (SiteMap.CurrentNode.HasParentNodes == true) 
        {
            // I'd like to loop trough each parent till the RootNode
            foreach (SiteMapNode Snode in SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNodes)
            {
                <a href="@Snode.Url">@Snode >></a> 
            }
        } else {
            // If there is no parent just show current node
            <a href="@SiteMap.CurrentNode.Url.ToString()">@SiteMap.CurrentNode</a>
        }
    </div>
    <div>@DateTime.Now.Date.ToLongDateString()</div>
</div>
```

so how can i achieve this using Razor on View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()` HTML helper already does this. It is a templated control that you can modify by editing the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml` file, so basically you can get whatever HTML output you want.

If you still prefer to do it your way after knowing that, you can also do this with `MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.Ancestors` property (version 4 and up).